# Window not seen in Windows after "overrideredirect=true"

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I would like to have GUI window without window decoration (title bar, borders, etc...).
I use `wm overrideredirect` set to true, but then window manager doesn't see my application and it is not shown on taskbar or under <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> switch in Windows7.

Is it possible to have window without decorations but seen as normal application in window manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. Setting the [`overrideredirect`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M56) flag basically puts the window outside the control of the system window manager — it's how things like menus and tooltips actually work under the covers — and it is system policy that known windows have decorations.

There are a few slight exceptions that you might be able to enable in some circumstances with `wm attributes`:

- You can run in full-screen mode with [`wm attributes $w -fullscreen 1`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M10)
- You can tinker with [`wm attibutes $w -type`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M19) to find something that has the effect you want, *but only on Unix* (it's a platform-specific feature).

I suspect neither applies to you.

Comment: Thanks. In that case I will stay with decorated window.